# template friend function in another namespace and CRTP

Tags: c++

This has been driving me crazy for the past couple hours, and I cannot seem to get around this problem. I have distilled the problem down to these 60 lines of code (including a main function).

```
#include <iostream>

namespace n1 {

// the general definition
template <class X, class Y> void f(X&, const Y&)
{
    std::cout << "general template definition.\n";
}

} // namespace n1
namespace n2 {

// CRTP
template <class Derived> class A 
{
    int data;

    // partial function template specialization for n1::f, and declare
    // it a friend too, so that it may access the data attribute of A
    template <class Y> friend void n1::f(A<Derived>& a, const Y& y);

}; // class A

} // namespace n2
namespace n1 {

// implementation for this particular function template specialization
template <class Derived, class Y> void f(n2::A<Derived>& a, const Y& y)
{
    std::cout << "partial template specialization: " << a.data << "\n";
}

} // namespace n1
namespace n2 {

// Another class!
class B : public A<B> 
{

}; // class B    
} // namespace n2
namespace n1 {

// --------------------
// tricky part is here!
// --------------------
template <class Y> void f(n2::B& b, const Y& y)
{
    // FAIL! not a friend! How?
    f(static_cast<n2::A<n2::B>&>(b), y);
}

} // namespace n1

int main()
{
    n2::B b;
    int x;
    n1::f(b, x); // should print "partial template specialization"
    return 0;
}
```

So, what I "want" is to have the compiler select my function template specialization of `n1::f` whenever it is invoked with a concrete subclass of `A<Derived>`. In order to make sure that the compiler favors my specialization, I need to supply, for every subclass (`B` in this case), also a template specialization for `n1::f` that simply delegates the call. When that happens, I expect the `data` member variable of `A<Derived>` to be accessible to `n1::f`, because I declare `n1::f` to be a friend of `A<Derived>`. However, GCC complains that `A<Derived>::data` is private and inaccessible, [see this snippet on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f36f9bdf9edc7f9).

Is this construction possible? If so, how can I get around the compiler complaining that `A<Derived>::data` is not accessible? (Making it public is not an option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class definition must look like this:

```
template <class Derived> class A 
{
    int data;
    template <class D, class Y> friend void n1::f(A<D>& a, const Y& y);
};
```

In fact, function declaration is:

```
template <class Derived, class Y> void f(n2::A<Derived>& a, const Y& y)
```

While your friend declaration is:

```
template <class Y> friend void n1::f(A<Derived>& a, const Y& y);
```

In this case, they are different beasts and that's why you receive that error. As you can see, template parameters lists are different. That's not a declaration of a function with a separated definition. They are two different function templates, one declared and the other one both declared and defined.
In other terms, in your code you are declaring a friend function but you never define it. On the other side, you introduced a free function template that cannot read the `data` member for it's private and the function isn't a friend one of `A<Derived>`.

---

See it running on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NvOJbS8TyiiwOP3x).

Comment: I see... This works! Wow. Can you explain why the extra template parameter `D` is *necessary*? It looks to me like my friend declaration would enable any `A<Derived>` to be a friend, but it seems you'd need a separate template parameter for that.

Comment: @rwols I added more details. They are two different function templates, for they have different template parameters lists and different arguments. I don't know how to explain it better...